# How to get data get from multiple tables and update using EF

Tags: c#, api, entity-framework, crud

I have successfully inserted data into two tables which are working fine. Now I am just stuck as to how I can get the details from both tables and update them. After inserting, I want to query both tables using an id and get the records, and then use the Id to update.

This is what I am looking for.

1. get data from two tables
2. update tables(pass id)
3. It must be an API that communicates with my classes because I want to display the data from the view

**DB Models**

```
1. 
public class WholesaleRateSheetMarkup
{
    [Key]
    public int RateSheetMarkupId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ResellerId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string RatesheetName { get; set; }

}


2.
public class WholesaleRateSheet
{
    [Key]
    public int RateSheetId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int RateSheetMarkupId { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Peak { get; set; }
    public bool IsSouthAfricanRate { get; set; }
    public bool IsInertnationRate { get; set; }
    public bool IsSpecificRate { get; set; }
    public int DestinationGroupSetId { get; set; }
    public int DestinationGroupId { get; set; }
    public string DestinationLookup { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByUsername { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedByUsername { get; set; }

}
```

**My controller: This controller calls service class**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[controller]/addRateSheet/{resellerId}/{productName}")]
    public IActionResult AddRateSheet(int resellerId, string productName , int destinationGroupSetId, [FromBody]List<RateSheetSummary> rateSheetSummaries)
    {
        RateSheetService rateSheetService = new RateSheetService();
        return Ok(rateSheetService.SaveRateSheet(resellerId, productName, rateSheetSummaries));
    }
```

**This is how I am saving to the database**

```
    public RateSheetModel SaveRateSheet(int resellerId, string productName, [FromBody]List<RateSheetSummary> rateSheetSummaries)
    {
        int latestId;
        RateSheetModel rateSheetModel = new RateSheetModel();
        try
        {
            #region Save rate sheet to the tabase
            if (RateSheetObj != null)
            {
               
                #region WholesaleRateSheetMarkup
                var wholesaleRateSheetMarkup = new WholesaleRateSheetMarkup
                {
                    ResellerId = resellerId,
                    RatesheetName = productName,
                };
                 _Context.WholesaleRateSheetMarkup.Add(wholesaleRateSheetMarkup);
                 _Context.SaveChanges();

                //get latest RateSheetMarkupId 
                latestId = wholesaleRateSheetMarkup.RateSheetMarkupId;
                #endregion

                #region WholesaleRateSheet

                #region commented out
                List<WholesaleRateSheet> wholesaleRateSheets = new List<WholesaleRateSheet>();
                foreach (var item in rateSheetSummaries)
                {
                    wholesaleRateSheets.Add(new WholesaleRateSheet()
                    {
                        RateSheetMarkupId = latestId,
                        CountryCode = item.CountryCode,
                        Description = item.Description,
                        Peak = item.Peak,
                        IsSouthAfricanRate = item.IsSouthAfricanRate,
                        IsSpecificRate = item.IsSpecificRate,
                        DestinationGroupSetId =  1,
                        DestinationGroupId = 1,
                        DestinationLookup = item.DestinationLookup,
                        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
                    }); ;
                    _Context.WholesaleRateSheet.AddRange(wholesaleRateSheets);
                    _Context.SaveChanges();
                }
                #endregion
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Trying to fetch data from my tables. At this point, I don't know how to continue further as I want to get the details and so that I can bind the data from the view.

```
   public RateSheetModel getRatesheetDetails(int rateSheetMarkupId)
    {
        RateSheetModel model = new RateSheetModel();
        using (var context = new AppClientZoneContext())
        {
            var select = (from rsm in context.WholesaleRateSheetMarkup
                         join rs in context.WholesaleRateSheet
                         on rsm.RateSheetMarkupId equals rs.RateSheetMarkupId
                         where rsm.RateSheetMarkupId == rateSheetMarkupId
                         select new
                         {
                              rsm.RatesheetName,
                              rs.CountryCode,
                              rs.Description,
                              rs.Peak,
                              rs.IsSouthAfricanRate,
                              rs.IsInertnationRate,
                              rs.RateSheetMarkupId,
                              rs.IsSpecificRate,
                              rs.DestinationGroupSetId,
                              rs.DestinationGroupId,
                              rs.DestinationLookup,
                              rs.CreatedDate,
                              rs.CreatedByUsername,
                              rs.LastUpdatedDate,
                              rs.UpdatedByUsername,
                          }).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return model;
    }
```

**Update API**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[controller]/updateRateSheet/{resellerId}/{ratesheetId}")]
    public IActionResult UpdateRateSheet(int resellerId, int ratesheetId, string productName)
    {
        RateSheetService UpdateRateSheetService = new RateSheetService();
        return Ok(UpdateRateSheetService.UpdateRateSheet(resellerId,ratesheetId, productName));
    }
```

Update function: I don't know how to best approach update functionality

```
    public RateSheetModel UpdateRateSheet(int resellerId, int rateSheetId, string productName)
    {
        RateSheetModel mm = new RateSheetModel();


        return mm;
    }
```

Comment: For starters `SaveRateSheet` is broken. A DbContext caches all changes and persists them once, in a single transaction, when you call `SaveChanges`. This way if you want to cancel/rollback changes, you can simply *not* call `SaveChanges` and let the DbContext get disposed.

Comment: Loading multiple objects is EF Core's job, not the code's. There shouldn't be any reason for joins. If the entities have proper relations between them EF Core will load all necessary related entities when a root entity is loaded. Finally, `Update` is actually `Save`. Load the objects you want to modify, modify them, then call `SaveChanges`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you please show min in code how I can implement it?